# Why does Exim's "sendmail" apparently do nothing for about 5 seconds before sending any mail?

Tags: smtp, exim, ubuntu-12.04

I'm having a problem where calling "sendmail" results in it just sitting there for about 5 seconds before doing anything. I tried calling it with "-d" and this is the output:

```
# sendmail -d [My email] <testmail 
Exim version 4.76 uid=0 gid=0 pid=3711 D=fbb95cfd
Berkeley DB: Berkeley DB 5.1.25: (January 28, 2011)
Support for: crypteq iconv() IPv6 GnuTLS move_frozen_messages DKIM
Lookups (built-in): lsearch wildlsearch nwildlsearch iplsearch cdb dbm dbmnz dnsdb dsearch nis nis0 passwd
Authenticators: cram_md5 plaintext
Routers: accept dnslookup ipliteral manualroute queryprogram redirect
Transports: appendfile/maildir/mailstore autoreply lmtp pipe smtp
Fixed never_users: 0
Size of off_t: 8
Compiler: GCC [4.6.3]
Library version: GnuTLS: Compile: 2.12.14
                         Runtime: 2.12.14
Library version: PCRE: Compile: 8.12
                       Runtime: 8.12 2011-01-15
Total 12 lookups
WHITELIST_D_MACROS: "OUTGOING"
TRUSTED_CONFIG_LIST: "/etc/exim4/trusted_configs"
changed uid/gid: forcing real = effective
  uid=0 gid=0 pid=3711
  auxiliary group list: <none>
seeking password data for user "uucp": cache not available
getpwnam() succeeded uid=10 gid=10
```

It then sits and does nothing for 5 to 10 seconds, before continuing.

```
configuration file is /var/lib/exim4/config.autogenerated
log selectors = 00000ffc 00612001
cwd=/root 3 args: sendmail -d [My email]
...etc
```

What is it doing during this time, and how to do I get it to stop? Frustratingly, specifying "-odb" to make it run in the background does *not* solve the problem - it backgrounds *after* the delay.

I'm running Exim 4.76 on Ubuntu Server 12.04. Exim is configured to send all email through a smarthost.

Here's the output of strace:

```
 getpwnam() succeeded uid=10 gid=10
 open("/etc/resolv.conf", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 4
 open("/etc/resolv.conf", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 4
 open("/etc/host.conf", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 4
 open("/etc/hosts", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC)  = 4
 open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 4
 open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_dns.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 4
 open("/etc/hosts", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC)  = 4
 configuration file is /var/lib/exim4/config.autogenerated
```

The "libnss_dns.so.2" line is the last one printed before the delay.

Comment: Can you run `strace -e open sendmail -d [My email] <testmail` and add the output to your OP?  That might give you a pointer as to where the block is. Failing that, remove the `-e open` for a spammier view of all the system calls.

Comment: 5 seconds? Sounds like a DNS issue.

Comment: Output of strace added.

Comment: Are you sure all (relay)-hosts in the sendmail config can be accessed quickly ? If sendmail has to wait a bit for DNS resolves to complete this sort of thing can happen. Put those hosts temporarily in /etc/hosts en see it that improves things.

Comment: Aha! That was the solution. The top DNS server entry was pointing to a defunct server. Removed it, and now it's super-quick. If you submit that as an answer I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: Check your server config.  Is ident disabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered by Tonny in the comments - the first DNS server was invalid so it was waiting for it to timeout. Removing the invalid DNS entry solved the problem.